# Returning local variable to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I need to send some parameters  to controller on form submitting.
With anchor there's no problem, but in form I dont get parameters in controller.

```
= form_tag objects_path("Sample" => "Test", :return_param => @param_value), :method => :get do
  = submit_tag 'Submit', :id=>'objects_submit'

link_to 'Link Title', objects_path("Sample" => "Test", :return_param => @param_value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to include it as part of the form submission instead as mixing GET and POST parameters can lead to confusion.

Add this inside the `form_tag` block:

```
= hidden_field_tag("Sample", "Test")
= hidden_field_tag(:return_param, @param_value)
```

You can always see what parameters are being received by your controller by watching `log/development.log`.

Comment: so, forms withs GET method cant have parameteres in action, yes?

Comment: Yeah, small typo there. Good to hear.